# How to make getRunningAppProcesses() work in Android L and Higher

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to develop an app for Android which will just show a Toast message saying "WhatsApp is Running" when user opened the WhatsApp application.

I'm using the following code to do the work but it is not working. Is there any way to make it work on all devices including Android L and M

I searched a lot for one day and can't get proper answer.

```
public void WhatsApp() {

        final String str = "";
        int whatsapplaunched = 0;
        int whatsappclosed =0;
        int whatsapplaunches = 1;

        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();

        for ( ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess: runningAppProcessInfo ) {
            Log.d(appProcess.processName.toString(),"is running");
            if (appProcess.processName.equals("com.whatsapp")) {
                if (appProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND){
                    if (whatsapplaunched == 0 ){
                        whatsapplaunched = 1;
                        Log.d(str,"WhatsApp has been launched");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WhatsApp is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } // Last If Ends
                    else if (whatsappclosed == 1){
                        whatsapplaunches++;
                        whatsappclosed = 0;
                        Log.d(String.valueOf(whatsapplaunches),"counter");
                    } // Else If Ends
                } // 2 IF Ends
                else {
                    whatsappclosed = 1;
                    Log.d(str,"WhatsApp has been closed");
                } // Else Ends
            } // Main If Ends
        } // For Ends
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
  ActivityManager manager=(ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processes=manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    int i=0;
    for(ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo process:processes)
    {
       if(process.processName.contains("com.whatsapp"))
                {
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Whatsapp running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
    }
```

Comment: It is working in Kitkat...I need to make it work on Android L and higher